# Ensure a random javascript object selection isn't selected twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to store the random selection of a function in an array so that in future runs of the random function the property that was previously picked will not be selected. For example, I want it so if England is selected at random then, future runs of this function will omit England.

**Javascript Object**

```
var countryDataObj = {
    England: { Title: "England", imageUrl: "", Total: 70 },
    Spain: { Title: "Spain", imageUrl: "", Total: 57 },
    Wales: { Title: "Wales", imageUrl: "", Total: 52 },
    Germany: { Title: "Germany", imageUrl: "", Total: 16 },
    Ireland: { Title: "Ireland", imageUrl: "", Total: 14 },
    Russia: { Title: "Russia", imageUrl: "", Total: 19 },
    Portugal: { Title: "Portugal", imageUrl: "", Total: 32 },
    Wales: { Title: "Wales", imageUrl: "", Total: 52 },
    France: { Title: "France", imageUrl: "", Total: 49 }
}
```

**The current randomize function**

```
function returnCountry(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one would be an object-oriented approach.

```js
class CountryPicker {
  countries = [
    { Title: "England", imageUrl: "", Total: 70 },
    { Title: "Spain", imageUrl: "", Total: 57 },
    { Title: "Wales", imageUrl: "", Total: 52 },
    { Title: "Germany", imageUrl: "", Total: 16 },
    { Title: "Ireland", imageUrl: "", Total: 14 },
    { Title: "Russia", imageUrl: "", Total: 19 },
    { Title: "Portugal", imageUrl: "", Total: 32 },
    { Title: "Wales", imageUrl: "", Total: 52 },
    { Title: "France", imageUrl: "", Total: 49 }
  ];

  randomCountry() {
    if (this.countries.length == 0) throw new Error("None left");

    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.countries.length);

    const result = this.countries[index];
    this.countries.splice(index, 1);

    return result;
  }
}

const picker = new CountryPicker();
console.log(picker.randomCountry());
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BXAdgFwE4E8AKBLYA1gKbrQDeAUNNMEmurkTALzQDaV150AKrqiCIAuaACIAosgDm4ZABNRAGmi4AtmClEAquhAjRS3vFRg90AOwAGaAF9FnamV79B+gMoAHMLmSG1G7V19Qx5jUxEAVnNbey5uPgFhMQB1UyY-dU0dMwNlUJMzCIAmGId4lyTRAHESdWRMDIDs4LywswBGADZSuKcE1zEASXQiWQVlfyygsRC2kXaAFh6uPor9ACVEKFwwRqmc2YL5gE5lx2dE-Wx4dFREKVM9wIPWo+gAZhK7MtXLlLSIE9mjNXuFoMUzuU-qIAGLoMDIYBEIHTXJGN4LU42TgAXQA3BROPD5PBVAgUBhMAAKACU5DKuAAZtAqagABa4CAAOloFIYTC5gmk7OgzDF0EsdPZ6HgAHdoMgiPLxOgZegqaIAHLwRXQQSM1CiGkEsq0ZAQVAqeREAAeougAFkwOyuYyQPAblSnS7iXJSbToAAqaDszk8ugYRjcoVSdnGwlxM0W6AjCCIECW1ih7m8+hRtg+OS2-FlbPhvlRrkQDwgfBEKmF23KdrxsojO7oZAppjp1AE6jY7EUJOWjz4YikViK+Xk+g4cckWkEpPwQSC+BSKljwgkLm+0mzym0+Mrtfuzfbid7hF+skRrDH5c6iCrojri8L9DXkl3vnUmkns+r7vlun7freh4PgBT7msB56gTuX77r+c6PsOQFnhuCFXshkH-oBsGYR+iHgQe974TBL5Edhu64eRaGnm+8GXrRN5kX+DEYUxWEsUhbEoUe0HoYR3HETh-F4ZxIkgbxpECVBBFUaJNF8T+klCYxMlgXRHFCUAA)